# TFS Workspace issue: The path xxx is already mapped in workspace XXXXXXX

Tags: tfs, mapping, workspace

There

Please look at below for the error. Actually, I have list all the work spaces on the the server (I'm TFS admin), the work space "CNXA1ER-L0429_VS2012" cannot be found. Also the work space cannot be found via VS of local developer machine.

So I cannot remove the mapping.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the command line to delete the offending workspace:

```
tf workspace /delete /collection:yourserver:8080/tfs/yourcollection CNXA1ER-L0429_VS2012;ownerofworkspace
```

As a TFS Admin you should have the permission to administer the workspaces of others so this shouldn't be an issue to delete.

Another method is to use Attrice Sidekicks to delete the workspace which is easier to use but I have sometimes found in the past that it doesn't display all workspaces.

If you cannot find the workspace at all please try to clear the Visual Studio Cache per this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx

Comment: @Jadematrix, thanks for your answer. But it seems does not help.  See below:                                                                                                    TF14061: The workspace CNXA1ER-L0429_VS2012;Lee, Mac [COMMRES/MET/CN] does not exist.

Comment: Can you run this: "tf workspaces /computer:CNXA1ER-L0429_VS2012 /collection:http://cnxa1eres-vm31:8080/tfs/centurion" (note that it's workspaces and not workspace), does it list no workspaces at all?  Sometimes the owner is listed differently depending on how it is managed.

Comment: It does not list the work space "CNXA1ER-L0429_VS2012" what I want to delete. I believe it does has been deleted from TFS already. But why I get the error message while mapping.

Comment: This link will show you how to reset your cache and the possible downsides of doing so.  It's an older link but still relevant.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help, I just delete C:\Users\<<Your Alias>>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0, it works!

Comment: Looks like the link to clear cache is down, for those who come here via google like me check this [link](https://errorhandlinginskills.wordpress.com/2018/07/28/how-to-clear-visual-studio-cache/) to clear cache

Answer (score 1):

In tfs  2015, the more easy is go to the table of the workspaces in the database and remove manually the old workspaces. This worked for me